# Spring security LDAP and API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, ldap

I'm trying to migrate a Spring Boot 2 project to Spring Boot 3 but I can't get away with configuring security.
My application has a web application that requires LDAP authentication and an API that requires browser authentication.
My problem is that all url are redirected to my login page, whereas I'd like /api to be redirected to my Swagger interface with httpBasic authentication.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter {

        @Autowired
        CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

        @Bean
        protected SecurityFilterChain apiSecurityFilterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.securityMatcher("/api/**").authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            });
            http.headers(header -> header.frameOptions().disable());
            http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
            http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
            return http.build();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        UserService userDetailsService;

        @Value("${ldap.urls}")
        private String ldapUrls;

        @Value("${ldap.base.dn}")
        private String ldapBaseDn;

        @Value("$ldap.search.ou")
        private String ldapSearchOu;

        @Value("${ldap.username}")
        private String ldapSecurityPrincipal;

        @Value("${ldap.password}")
        private String ldapPrincipalPassword;

        @Value("${ldap.user.dn.pattern}")
        private String ldapUserDnPattern;

        private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {"/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs", "/webjars/**", "/api"};

        @Bean
        protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(true).requestMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().requestMatchers("/").authenticated())
                    .formLogin(
                            login -> login.loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureUrl("/login?error"))
                    .logout(logout -> logout.invalidateHttpSession(false).clearAuthentication(true)
                            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll());
            http.headers(header -> header.frameOptions().disable());
            http.sessionManagement(session -> session.maximumSessions(1).and().invalidSessionUrl("/login?expired"));
            return http.build();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication().ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(new CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(userDetailsService))
                    .userSearchFilter(ldapUserDnPattern).groupSearchBase(ldapSearchOu).contextSource()
                    .url(ldapUrls + ldapBaseDn).managerDn(ldapSecurityPrincipal).managerPassword(ldapPrincipalPassword);
        }

    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UtilisateurRepository utilisateurRepository;

  public UserService(final UtilisateurRepository utilisateurRepository) {
    this.utilisateurRepository = utilisateurRepository;
  }

  /**
   * loadUserByUsername.
   *
   * @param username Le nom d'utilisateur
   * @return L'utilisateur
   */
  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    final UtilisateurDao utilisateurDao = utilisateurRepository.findByLogin(username);
    return new User(utilisateurDao.getMatricule().toString(), null, null);
  }

  /**
   * loadUserAuthorities.
   *
   * @param username Le nom d'utilisateur
   * @return Le profil de l'utilisateur
   */
  public List<GrantedAuthority> loadUserAuthorities(final String username) {
    final UtilisateurDao utilisateurDao = utilisateurRepository.findByLogin(username);
    if (utilisateurDao != null && utilisateurDao.getProfil() != null) {
      return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(utilisateurDao.getProfil());
    }
    return new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
  }

}
```

Logs

```
2023-07-13T09:15:52.921+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.929+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.930+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Request requested invalid session id 87847793E2A3E57F9B41DE144174BE4D
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.930+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mw.s.SimpleRedirectInvalidSessionStrategy[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting new session (if required) and redirecting to '/login?expired'
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.976+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Redirecting to /login?expired
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.985+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /login?expired
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.986+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-07-13T09:15:52.987+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /login?expired
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.945+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /api
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.948+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.949+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36ms.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.950+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36ms.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint[0;39m [2m:[0;39m No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@ffd6833
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.956+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /error
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.958+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.962+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Saved request http://localhost:8081/error?continue to session
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.963+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Redirecting to http://localhost:8081/login
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.968+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Securing GET /login
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.968+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[2m2023-07-13T09:16:16.969+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m5028[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Secured GET /login
```

Comment: please edit our question to include your full DEBUG or TRACE logs for spring security when asking.

Comment: you implement this interface https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html and set it in yout httpsecurity exceptionhandler configuration https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/ExceptionHandlingConfigurer.html#defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint,org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher) in the interface you add what redirection you want to do

Comment: and no i dont have a code example